# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i was trying to do the instant comment with ajax and i am getting an error, saying uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null i coudnt fix it, can anyone help me to fixed this? i was following the tutorial(http://www.allaboutphp.com/php-ajax-live-comment-system/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function sendPost() {
            var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
            var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
                if (comment && name) {
                    $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'post_comments.php',
                            data: {
                            user_comm: comment,
                            user_name: name
                            },
                            success: function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            document.getElementById("commentList").innerHTML = response + document.getElementById("commentList").innerHTML;
                            document.getElementById("comment").value = "";
                            document.getElementById("username").value = "";

                            }
                        });
                    }

            return false;
            }
    </script>
```

this is my index page to show the comments....

```
                            <?php
                                $servername = "localhost";
                                $username = "root";
                                $password = "";

                                // Create connection
                                $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
                                $db = mysqli_select_db($con,"Review");
                                $qry = mysqli_query($con,"select name,comment,post_time from comments order by post_time desc");
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry))
                            {
                              $name=$row['name'];
                              $comment=$row['comment'];
                              $time=$row['post_time'];
                        ?>


<div class="detailBox" id="detailBox">
    <div class="titleBox">
      <label>Comment Box</label>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="commentBox">

        <p class="taskDescription">test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="actionBox" id="actionBox">
        <ul class="commentList" id="commentList">
            <li>
                <div class="commenterImage">
                  <p><?php echo $name;?>:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="commentText">
                    <p class=""><?php echo $comment;?></p> <span class="date sub-text">on <?php echo $time;?></span>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php
         }
        ?>
       <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPost();">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your name" / required="" id="username">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" placeholder="your comments....." required=""></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: is `document.getElementById("commentList")` actually found?

Comment: how to add codes in comment?

Comment: in the tutorial i see document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML = response + document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML;

Comment: i have added the html codes also.

Comment: @Sazny14 you cannot use innerHtml() with UL tag, please try appending LI or alternate function, the tutorial which you mentioned you div tag to add the comment, but you are using UL LI tag

Comment: thanks @veeran, i found the error as u said.